# What areas open when I place the Lordvessel on the Firelink Altar?

Tags: dark-souls

I just acquired the Lordvessel and placed it on the Firelink Altar. When I did, a cutscene showed 3 orange barriers opening. Where can I find those barriers/doors, and what areas do they lead to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> There are several orange fog gates in the game which can only be
>   lifted by obtaining and placing the Lordvessel at the Altar. These fog
>   gates can be found in **Anor Londo**, **Tomb of the Giants** and **Demon Ruins**.

http://darksouls.wikidot.com/fog-gate

Tomb of the giants (past catacombs): The fog gate blocks the way to the boss.

Anor Lando: Fog gate is on boundary between Anor Lando and the Dukes Archives (preventing access to the archives). Exit left from the Anor lando bonfire or head straight from where you enter from Sen's Fortress

Demon Runes: Fog gate is in demon ruins and blocks your access to the demon firesage boss and Lost Izalith. The fog gate is in the area of the demon ruins that is only accessible once you defeat the ceaseless discharge boss.

Answer (score 2):

The Lordvessel unlocks

- Demon Ruins boss (Demon Firesage) and **Lost Izalith**, which comes after said boss (under Blighttown)
- **Tomb of the Giants** (after Catacombs)
- **Duke's Archives** (at the start of Anor Londo, to the left from the first bonfire)